# How to detect beforehand if Azure ARM script will change customData?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, cloud-init

I'm trying to deploy a Ubuntu virtual machine in Azure using an Azure DevOps Release pipeline, an Azure ARM template and a cloud-init script.

I set up a script that first validates the ARM template using an `AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3` task then runs `Get-AzResourceGroupDeploymentWhatIfResult` command using the `AzurePowerShell@5` task and finally deploys the template using another `AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3` task. This all works the first time if the VM does not exist.

The problem comes on second and subsequent attempts. If the cloud-init template has changed the Validation task passes, the `Get-AzResourceGroupDeploymentWhatIfResult` does not see any relevant changes but the deployment task fails with this error:

```
2020-07-26T13:47:33.2408130Z ##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.  
2020-07-26T13:47:33.2424660Z ##[error]Details:  
2020-07-26T13:47:33.2426481Z ##[error]PropertyChangeNotAllowed: Changing property 'customData' is not allowed.  
2020-07-26T13:47:33.2429346Z ##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting  
2020-07-26T13:47:33.2431470Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

Obviously this is because I changed the cloud-init script. If I then delete the VM and redeploy it works as expected.

I would like to detect this situation and delete the VM before the deployment fails so that the VM is recreated only when it needs to be. Neither the Validate deployment nor the `Get-AzResourceGroupDeploymentWhatIfResult` seem to pick the situation up. Any ideas how to do this?

After asking this question I had another bright spark idea. This is to call `(get-azvm -name my-vm-name).OSProfile.CustomData` and compare the result with the custom data the deployment is about to apply. Alas this didn't work either as the cmdlet does not return the custom data the virtual machine was created with.

Comment: Is @4c74356b41's reply helpful?

Comment: @Cece Song - it isn't helpful. Not that I'm unhappy with it, but it doesn't get me any further with my goals.

Comment: Does the `Get-AzResourceGroupDeploymentWhatIfResult` command work if you run it in azure powershell, without using DevOps? It seems your issue is more related to Azure VM, not Azure Devops.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT My aim is to get DevOps to detect that the VM needs to be deleted before applying the ARM Template. If there is a way that doesn't use Get-AzResourceGroupDeploymentWhatIfResult I'd be glad to hear of it. And no Get-AzResourceGroupDeploymentWhatIfResult doesn't work wherever I run it.

Comment: Do you create the pipeline in Azure or in DevOps (https://dev.azure.com/xxx)?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I created it in DevOps

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to achieve your requirement. DevOps is not able to detect the VM by default. If script can do that, DevOps can call the script. But if script can not do that, then DevOps has no way to detect the VM.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Is there a way for DevOps to detect if a source file was changed since the last deployment?

Comment: You can enable CI trigger, CI trigger cause a pipeline to run whenever you push an update to the specified branches or you push specified tags. Or you can use script to detect the changes: https://pumpingco.de/blog/run-an-azure-pipelines-job-only-if-source-code-has-changed/

Answer (score 0):

[Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) is usually pretty good at detecting changes which require the resource to be recreated. If you are willing to switch from ARM templates, [`azurerm_linux_virtual_machine`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/linux_virtual_machine.html) would be the element to try.

> custom_data - (Optional)
>
> The Base64-Encoded Custom Data which should be used for this Virtual Machine. **Changing this forces a new resource to be created.**

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question. The question is about ARM templates. Telling someone who is having a problem with a tool "you won't have that problem if you use a completely different tool" isn't helpful.

Comment: Fair enough. I always consider Terraform "close enough" to ARM templates, at it also fits well into Azure DevOps release pipelines, but I could have also put it in a comment.

Comment: sorry but terraform is such a bad tool, its even hard to put into words.

Comment: @AlexAIT Sadly as others have said using Teraform is not an option for me. It may however be for one or two that pass across this question via their web searches so I do think it is a valuable answer to keep around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain there is no generic way of doing that, I've just checked Azure REST Api reference and it doesnt really tell you read-only fields on the compute resources. I think I saw some properties marked for some of the resource providers, but you cant really rely on that.